# Cocoapods, pod install error, How do I fix this?

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

suman@groot:~/ALL_MINE/REACT/REACT_NATIVE/PhotoEditor$ **cd ios**
suman@groot:~/ALL_MINE/REACT/REACT_NATIVE/PhotoEditor/ios$ **pod install**

---

Adding a custom script phase for Pod RNFBApp: [RNFB] Core Configuration

Auto-linking React Native modules for target `PhotoEditor`: RNFBApp, RNFBFirestore, RNGestureHandler, RNScreens, RNVectorIcons, react-native-image-picker, react-native-pager-view, and react-native-safe-area-context

**Analyzing dependencies**

Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`

Fetching podspec for `RCT-Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec`

Fetching podspec for `boost` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/boost.podspec`

Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`

**Downloading dependencies**

- Installing BoringSSL-GRPC (0.0.7)
- Installing CocoaAsyncSocket (7.6.5) Installing DoubleConversion (1.1.6)
- Installing FBLazyVector
  (0.66.1)
- Installing FBReactNativeSpec (0.66.1) Installing Firebase
  (8.9.0)
- Installing FirebaseCore (8.9.0)
- Installing
  FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (8.9.0)
- Installing FirebaseFirestore (8.9.1)
- Installing Flipper (0.99.0)
- Installing Flipper-Boost-iOSX
  (1.76.0.1.11)
- Installing Flipper-DoubleConversion (3.1.7)
- Installing
  Flipper-Fmt (7.1.7)
- Installing Flipper-Folly (2.6.7)
- Installing
  Flipper-Glog (0.3.6)

> [!] /usr/bin/bash -c  set -e
> #!/bin/bash
>
> ## Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
>
> ## This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
>
> ## LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
>
> set -e
>
> PLATFORM_NAME="${PLATFORM_NAME:-iphoneos}"
> CURRENT_ARCH="${CURRENT_ARCH}"
>
> if [ -z "$CURRENT_ARCH" ] || [ "$CURRENT_ARCH" == "undefined_arch" ];
> then
> # Xcode 10 beta sets CURRENT_ARCH to "undefined_arch", this leads to incorrect linker arg.
> # it's better to rely on platform name as fallback because architecture differs between simulator and device
>
> ```
> if [[ "$PLATFORM_NAME" == *"simulator"* ]]; then
>     CURRENT_ARCH="x86_64"
> else
>     CURRENT_ARCH="armv7"
> fi fi
> ```
>
> export CC="$(xcrun -find -sdk $PLATFORM_NAME cc) -arch $CURRENT_ARCH
> -isysroot $(xcrun -sdk $PLATFORM_NAME --show-sdk-path)" export CXX="$CC"
>
> ## Remove automake symlink if it exists if [ -h "test-driver" ]; then
>
> ```
> rm test-driver fi
> ```
>
> ./configure --host arm-apple-darwin
>
> ## Fix build for tvOS cat << EOF >> src/config.h /* Add in so we have Apple Target Conditionals */
>
> #ifdef **APPLE**
> #include <TargetConditionals.h>
> #include <Availability.h>
> #endif /* Special configuration for AppleTVOS */
> #if TARGET_OS_TV
> #undef HAVE_SYSCALL_H
> #undef HAVE_SYS_SYSCALL_H
> #undef OS_MACOSX
> #endif /* Special configuration for ucontext */
> #undef HAVE_UCONTEXT_H
> #undef PC_FROM_UCONTEXT
> #if defined(**x86_64**)
> #define PC_FROM_UCONTEXT uc_mcontext->__ss.__rip
> #elif defined(**i386**)
> #define PC_FROM_UCONTEXT uc_mcontext->__ss.__eip
> #endif EOF
>
> ## Prepare exported header include EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR="exported/glog" mkdir -p exported/glog cp -f src/glog/log_severity.h
>
> "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/" cp -f src/glog/logging.h
> "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/" cp -f src/glog/raw_logging.h
> "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/" cp -f src/glog/stl_logging.h
> "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/" cp -f src/glog/vlog_is_on.h
> "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
>
> checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c checking
> whether build environment is sane... yes checking for
> arm-apple-darwin-strip... no checking for strip... strip checking for
> a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p checking for gawk... no
> checking for mawk... mawk checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
> checking whether make supports nested variables... yes checking for
> arm-apple-darwin-gcc...  -arch armv7 -isysroot  checking whether the C
> compiler works... no /usr/bin/bash: line 24: xcrun: command not found
> /usr/bin/bash: line 24: xcrun: command not found
> /home/suman/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/Flipper-Glog/0.3.6-1dfd6/missing:
> Unknown `--is-lightweight' option Try` /home/suman/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/Flipper-Glog/0.3.6-1dfd6/missing
> --help' for more information configure: WARNING: 'missing' script is too old or missing configure: error: in
> `/home/suman/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/Flipper-Glog/0.3.6-1dfd6': configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables See` config.log' for more details

suman@groot:~/ALL_MINE/REACT/REACT_NATIVE/PhotoEditor/ios$

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by making sure the Command Line Tools option was set to a valid option in Xcode (in Preferences -> Locations).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, export LDFLAGS and CPPFLAGS in .zshrc cause same error.
If you set it in .zshrc or something similar, try comment out it.